# Markdown plugin for IntelliJ not showing preview

Tags: intellij-idea, markdown

On Windows 10, I'm using IntelliJ version 2022.2.2.
I have the bundled Markdown plugin enabled:

[image: plugin]

However, when working on a markdown file (.md), the preview is completely gray, as visible on the right side of the following image:

[image: preview]

Do you know what can be causing this issue, and how to solve it?

I've tried to disable and enable the plugin again, or to open different markdown files from different IntelliJ projects, but the problem remains the same.

Comment: Does it help if you add `ide.browser.jcef.gpu.disable=true` in Help | Edit Custom Properties and restart the IDE?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Please add `ide.browser.jcef.gpu.disable=true` in Help | Edit Custom Properties and restart the IDE.

This option disables GPU acceleration for the browser component (JCEF) which seems to fail on your hardware for some reason.

Comment: Thank you, this solved it! In my case I'm running Intellij in a VM

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me on IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.5 (Ultimate Edition) on Mac.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me (2023.2.1 UE on Ubuntu).

Comment: Not working for me.  "IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.4 (Ultimate Edition)"

Comment: If you still have issues, please file bugs at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the logs attached (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data).

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. (2023.1.2 Ultimate Edition on MacOs in UTM virtual machine)

Comment: @Daniel please see my comment above.

Comment: I just updated to 2023.3.3 and it works now. Thanks CrazyCoder

Answer (score 2):

I tried the above setting the custom properties and it didnt work.

But for me, Help -> Find Action -> Choose Boot Java Runtime for the IDE and selecting the latest version -> Save and restart worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is visibly an IntelliJ bug. I am not using *Editor and Preview*, but I got it on IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2 (Community Edition) in *Preview* mode. Switching to *Editor* then back to *Preview* sufficed to workaround.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to add `ide.browser.jcef.gpu.disable=true` in **Help | Edit Custom Properties** and restart the IDE, It did not work for me.

I noticed that I am running Idea application as Administrator every time, so I started the app in normal mode, and worked fine., without any addition in properties.

#Markdown #preview #MD #file #IDEA #IntelliJ